# Admin Portal 403 Forbidden post LDAP

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have configured a read-only ldap store for my WSO2 api manager and when trying to hit the /admin portal post configuration I am getting a 403 forbidden error.  I changed the default superadmin account to a custom one to map to my ldap directory and am trying to find a way to map my main admin account to be able to login to the admin page (beyond /carbon).  Do you know if there is a way to manually map a user to this portal / page or other permission that is needed (since can't login to the page)?

Thanks
Nick

Comment: Have you added the LDAP as a secondary user store?

Comment: I added it as the primary user store

Comment: I did it in the deployment.toml file as the user_store.properties configuration and is working for the carbon login and other stuff when adding users to internal roles.

Comment: I think easiest way is to, add you LDAP as a secondary userstore and then map the new roles and scopes using the super admin residing in the Primary userstore.  https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/administer/managing-users-and-roles/managing-user-roles/#adding-role-mappings

Comment: Or try mappings the roles/scopes in `<APIM-HOME>/repository/resources/tenant-conf.json`

Comment: Would you happen to know all the scopes needed for full admin rights to the /admin site?  I can see some apim:admin_ scopes but just wondering all that are needed

Comment: You can find them here. https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/administer/managing-users-and-roles/managing-user-roles/

Comment: Ok, for some reason doing the tenant-conf.json is not picking it up either.  Let me revert the ldap config back to the default / remove these mappings and see if I can get this to work with the secondary user store configuration.